# Developing UI's in GNU/Smalltalk

Tags: user-interface, gtk, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

Which frameworks or packages exists for developing UI's with GNU/Smalltalk? There seems to be a [GTK+ binding](http://smalltalk.gnu.org/tags/gtk) but not much documentation about it.

For example in VisualAge Smalltalk there is WidgetKit and in Squeak there is Morphic with Announcements or change/update event protocol. What would be their corresponding options in GNU/Smalltalk?

Comment: As for me developing UI in GNU Smalltalk is a bit weird. Originally Smalltalk was UI based environment, and GNU went to the dark side with command line. Why do you want to develop UI with gnu when you can use Pharo?

Comment: Because GTK+ is a 15-year UI library + thousands of users, books, support, etc. Pharo still lacks a decent UI builder, have very few Morphic users, unmature libraries like Spec,... actually why would I use Pharo for doing UI? :)

Comment: Kinda funny you say that. But for my choosing of pharo a big role to it played Morphic. Morphic is the standard GUI in pharo , its what pharo uses and hence many libraries and apps rely on it, the entire IDE is based on it, there is no way to avoid Morphic. About Morphic itself its true is not as big as GTK+ , but its very reliable GUI on all 3 platforms. On the other hand GTK+ is notorious for bad support for both MacOS and Windows. Personally if I had to chose a GUI I would choose QT. Why use Morphic ? Morphic is elegantly simple for me its just the cleanest design for GUI and its smalltalk.

Answer (score 3):

The GTK+ binding is the "official" way to develop UIs with GNU Smalltalk.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.